# store IPv6 to database after being converted to binary

Tags: php, mysql, binary, ipv6

I have an `ip` table with `VARBINARY` fields: `ip_start` and `ip_end`
Now I have a problem,

```
$ip=('2001:255:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff');
$binary=unpack("A16",inet_pton($ip));
var_dump($binary);
```

Now, how to store `$binary_start` and `$binary_end` to `ip` table?
Do I need any wrapping of data(such as bin2hex)?

```
"INSERT INTO `ip_table` (`id`, `binary_start`, `binary_end`) VALUES
(1,".$binary_start.",".$binary_end.");"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Despite the title, that's the exact problem you're facing and solutions listed there will fix it.

Comment: @CBroe - He already mentions `varbinary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a `BINARY`/`VARBINARY` type, which could be used to store binary data directly, without compute it into a hexadecimal representation.

```
CREATE TABLE `%s` (
    `binary_start` BINARY( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    `binary_end` VARBINARY( 20 ) NOT NULL,
);
```

If you use prepared statements and pass the values without concatenating them to a string, the binary data will be inserted "as is".

```
/** @var $database \PDO */
$stmt = $database->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `ip_table` (`binary_start`, `binary_end`) VALUES ( :start, :end );' );
$stmt->bindValue( ':start', $binaryStart );
$stmt->bindValue( ':end', $binaryEnd );
```